# Is there library similar to urllib2 of Python?

Tags: go, package

In python we have urllib2 and httplib but I've been searching in Go! page and I only found an http lib, I don't know if this lib is the same.

Comment: Go's default http client is excellent, and you really don't need anything else. just use it!

Comment: Already [discussed on the golang-nuts mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/RnBF9Tlzfqc/discussion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you are looking for in the urllib2, because it has several features. But, I have found this code with the main requisite: http://play.golang.org/p/Iq91LjcAka

I hope it is what you're looking for. I also found it in this thread of conversation in google groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Golang-Nuts/RnBF9Tlzfqc

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go behind the main [golang `http` package](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/), you can use a project like [go-metainspector](https://github.com/fern4lvarez/go-metainspector).
It is similar to [python urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) which return the meta-information of the page, such as headers.

> go-metainspector is a web scraper package that provides access to basic info and meta tags of a given URL.

```
  url := "http://www.cloudcontrol.com/pricing"
  MI, err := metainspector.New(url)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error: %v", err)
  } else {
    fmt.Printf("\nURL: %s\n", MI.Url())
    fmt.Printf("Scheme: %s\n", MI.Scheme())
    fmt.Printf("Host: %s\n", MI.Host())
    fmt.Printf("Root: %s\n", MI.RootURL())
    fmt.Printf("Title: %s\n", MI.Title())
    fmt.Printf("Language: %s\n", MI.Language())
    fmt.Printf("Author: %s\n", MI.Author())
    fmt.Printf("Description: %s\n", MI.Description())
    fmt.Printf("Charset: %s\n", MI.Charset())
    fmt.Printf("Feed URL: %s\n", MI.Feed())
    fmt.Printf("Links: %v\n", MI.Links())
    fmt.Printf("Images: %v\n", MI.Images())
    fmt.Printf("Keywords: %v\n", MI.Keywords())
    fmt.Printf("Compatibility: %v\n", MI.Compatibility())
}
```